# how do I fix a point on a CSS line

Tags: css, transform

I am trying to make an analog clock with HTML,CSS and Javascript but I don´t know how to fix the clock hands when rotateing

```
.line {
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  height: 65px;
  transform: translate(100px);transform-origin: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at MDN's transform-origin docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin. Also, here's a working example in codepen: https://codepen.io/davidleininger/pen/abKyoKM/a1a592b1104fd860f013d827ebe44fc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This should do. Hope it helps you!**

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand')

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const timeInterval = 6;
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();

  const secondDegree = seconds * timeInterval;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDegree}deg)`;

  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minDegree = ((mins / 60) * 360) + 90;
  minHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minDegree}deg)`;

  const hours = now.getHours();
  const hourDegree = ((hours / 12) * 360) + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegree}deg)`;


}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

```css
html {
  /* background: #ededed url(https://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=881&blur=5); */
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.clock {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF, inset 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.clock-face {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 50%;
  right: 49%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hand {
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 2.58, 1, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock-face">
    <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helps. Just click the arrow checkmark button below the voting area. Thank you!